# How to trigger an event using parse push notification

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have integrated parse notifications.
But now I see some unauthenticated installations in my parse panel.
I want to send push notification and trigger an activity that will alert and close the app as those are unauthorized.

How can I trigger an activity or method in my main activity that will execute when particular parse push notification is received.

I would like some guidance on how I could trigger an event in my application if I receive a push notification that said "start"?

So if I get a notification and it only contained the value "start" it would then trigger an event to do something.